# How to trigger an event when Dataflow Pipeline is finished?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm running a Dataflow Template of my own from a Cloud function and I would like to do something when Pipeline is over.

Is there an official way of doing it ?

I can't use the `waitUntilFinish()` since my Cloud function won't last that long. So I need some kind of event, to trigger some other processes.

Pubsub sounds great but how to send a single message ?

Any idea would be great !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea is the following.

- Go to logs, select advanced filter (arrow on the right of the filter bar) and paste this custom filter

```
resource.type="dataflow_step" textPayload="Worker pool stopped."
```

If nothing is returned, try this

```
resource.type="gce_instance_group"
resource.labels.instance_group_name:"dataflow-"
jsonPayload.event_subtype="compute.instanceGroups.removeInstances"
jsonPayload.event_type="GCE_OPERATION_DONE"
```

You should see only your end of dataflow

- Go to export
- Select advance filter and paste again the filter
- Clic on create export
- set a sink name
- Set the destination to PubSub
- Select your topic
- Now, plug a function on this topic, it will be trigger only at the end of dataflow. *For the second filter*, it's not really at the end, but when the VM are destroy, thus all the processing is finished.

Comment: Upvote since subscibing to Log is an amazing trick that does exactly the job ! But Issue here is that this filter return a lot of logs from the same job, meaning that it will trigger the pubsub a lot of times. I'll dig for a better log and let you know if I find it.

Comment: For all my dataflow jobs, I have exactly 1 entry per job. I'm interested to know your use-case and your solution to it.

Comment: As for me, I have as many entry as worker loaded per job. Which makes sense. A better entry is looking for `resource.type="dataflow_step" textPayload="Worker pool stopped."`. If you agree, could you update your filter so that I can accept this answer ?

Comment: This filter return no result in my projects (dev and prod). I don't understand why. I see the `"Worker pool stopped."` in the dataflow graph (and logs section bellow the graph), but nowhere in the stackdriver logging section. Yes, it's better if it's work, and it doesn't work for me. I update my answer with both.

Comment: That's an interesting behaviour and probably a bug from Dataflow. Fun fact : I have the `Worker pool stopped` in europe-west4 but not in us-central. I won't even try to understand why ! :)

Comment: Hmmm, I already have unexpected behaviour like that. With composer, workflow worked great in US-central but not in EU, in fact the response to the API wasn't the same, thus composer didn't understand the EU response, there were too few data in the response.....